# Ruby - test for array

Tags: ruby, syntax

What is the right way to:

```
is_array("something") # => false         (or 1)

is_array(["something", "else"]) # => true  (or > 1)
```

or to get the count of items in it?

Comment: Do you want an actual array, or just something array-like?

Comment: There is no type-safety in Ruby. Don't worry about your variable being an array or not. The method should assume that it is, and go ahead and call count on it: my_array.count

Comment: Please read answers by zgchurch and DigitalRoss for more idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 587, accepted):

You probably want to use [`kind_of()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F).

```
>> s = "something"
=> "something"
>> s.kind_of?(Array)
=> false
>> s = ["something", "else"]
=> ["something", "else"]
>> s.kind_of?(Array)
=> true
```

Comment: There's also `is_a?` and `instance_of?`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a

Comment: Type checking is for Java. Go ahead and just call count on the variable. Write unit tests to make sure the method works as expected.

Comment: @user132447 actually java is type safe so you don't need to worry about checking any types

Comment: I downvoted this now since I don't think this is a good practice in a language like Ruby. The answer by @zgchurch is clearly a much more idiomatic approach to the question. In cases like this, I think it makes much more sense to try and figure out what the OP means, rather than blindly giving him a shotgun...

Comment: Just for the record, if you're checking for a string, it's `s.kind_of?(String)`

Comment: This feels more like Java. The Ruby way is to use [duck typing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DuckTyping). So better use `respond_to?` to check your assumptions.

Comment: Why would you want to use `kind_of?()` over other solutions?  Some explanation on the benefits of your answer over others would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: this answer has the added bonus of working in old versions. the answer below is invalid prior to version 1.9.

Answer (score 159):

Are you sure it **needs** to be an array? You may be able to use `respond_to?(method)` so your code would work for similar things that aren't necessarily arrays (maybe some other enumberable thing). If you do actually need an `array`, then the post describing the `Array#kind\_of?` method is best.

```
['hello'].respond_to?('each')
```

Comment: In this case I am sure it will be an Array. But nice to know this method too. +1

Comment: Interesting idea, I'm using push/pop on a data structure.  Would anything besides arrays respond to those methods?

Comment: If you want something more array-like, you may want `respond_to?(:to_ary)`.

Comment: In general, this is a good practice for OO development. I read where somebody said basically: don't imagine that you're calling methods on your objects. You're sending them messages. If an object knows how to respond to your message, you don't care what class it is, or whether it has a method named that, or whether it is dynamically creating a response via method_missing. The important thing is, can it respond to your message? This allow better abstraction of function and implementation. You can change what object you use later, as long as it still respond correctly.

Comment: The only issue with this is say I want to check if something is an indexed iterable, so arrays, linked lists, etc. would be cool, but I don't want key value stores like hashes?

Answer (score 63):

Instead of testing for an `Array,` just convert whatever you get into a one-level `Array,` so your code only needs to handle the one case.

```
t = [*something]     # or...
t = Array(something) # or...
def f *x
    ...
end
```

Ruby has various ways to harmonize an API which can take an object or an Array of objects, so, taking a guess at why you want to know if something *is* an Array, I have a suggestion.

The *splat* operator contains lots of magic [you can look up,](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/) or you can just call `Array(something)` which will add an Array wrapper if needed. It's similar to `[*something]` in this one case.

```
def f x
  p Array(x).inspect
  p [*x].inspect
end
f 1         # => "[1]"
f [1]       # => "[1]"
f [1,2]     # => "[1, 2]"
```

Or, you could use the *splat* in the parameter declaration and then `.flatten`, giving you a different sort of collector. (For that matter, you could call `.flatten` above, too.)

```
def f *x
  p x.flatten.inspect
end         # => nil
f 1         # => "[1]"
f 1,2       # => "[1, 2]"
f [1]       # => "[1]"
f [1,2]     # => "[1, 2]"
f [1,2],3,4 # => "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

And, thanks [gregschlom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365596/gregschlom), it's sometimes faster to just use `Array(x)` because when it's already an `Array` it doesn't need to create a new object.

Comment: So you are saying if it is a single item it makes it a array with a single item in it?

Comment: Yes, and if it already is an array it keeps it without adding a second array wrapper.

Comment: Don't forget: `[*nil] => []`. So you might end up with an empty array.

Comment: Using `Array(foo)` is much more efficient than `[*foo]`

Answer (score 41):

`[1,2,3].is_a? Array` evaluates to true.

Comment: What does this add to the answers that have been on the site for almost  seven years..?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker there isn't a concise answer that references ``is_a?`` in this whole thread. The closest is a ``[1,2,3].is_a? Enumerable``. I still think it's worth while to have this answer.

Comment: You know .. you're actually right ... I could've sworn I saw that up there earlier :-/ Have an upvote!

Answer (score 19):

It sounds like you're after something that has some concept of items. I'd thus recommend seeing if it is `Enumerable`. That also guarantees the existence of `#count`.

For example,

```
[1,2,3].is_a? Enumerable
[1,2,3].count
```

note that, while `size`, `length` and `count` all work for arrays, `count` is the right meaning here - (for example, `'abc'.length` and `'abc'.size` both work, but `'abc'.count` doesn't work like that).

Caution: a string is_a? Enumerable, so perhaps this isn't what you want... depends on your concept of an array like object.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
def is_array(a)
    a.class == Array
end
```

**EDIT**: The other answer is much better than mine.

Answer (score 6):

Also consider using `Array()`. From the [Ruby Community Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#array-coercion):

> Use Array() instead of explicit Array check or [*var], when dealing
>   with a variable you want to treat as an Array, but you're not certain
>   it's an array.

```
# bad
paths = [paths] unless paths.is_a? Array
paths.each { |path| do_something(path) }

# bad (always creates a new Array instance)
[*paths].each { |path| do_something(path) }

# good (and a bit more readable)
Array(paths).each { |path| do_something(path) }
```

Comment: This will produce unexpected results when passing a Hash because `to_a` is called on each argument added to the new array, so `Array({id: 100})` returns `[[:id, 100]]`