# Rspec and Capybara object matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, rspec2, capybara

Using Rails 3.0.5, RSpec 2 and Capybara 0.4.1.2 and I'am trying to write a controller spec for my SessionsController#new action.

```
it "assigns the empty session to a variable" do
  get :new
  assigns(:session).should == ActiveRecord::Base::Session.new
end
```

I'm using the ActiveRecord::Base namespace as it seems to clash with the Capybara Session class when I don't.

Here is the SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
     @session = Session.new
  end
end
```

RSpec doesn't seem to understand these are the same objects. Here is what my test returns:

```
 Failure/Error: assigns(:session).should == ActiveRecord::Base::Session.new
   expected: #<Session id: nil, session_id: nil, data: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
        got: #<Session id: nil, session_id: nil, data: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> (using ==)
   Diff:
 # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if you do

```
ActiveRecord::Base::Session.new == ActiveRecord::Base::Session.new
```

You would get false, as both these objects have a separate `object_id`.

Try this:

```
assigns(:session).should be_an(ActiveRecord::Base::Session)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Out of curiosity... would it make a difference if I use `be_an` or `be_an_instance_of` here?

Comment: Ah yes. `be_an` checks for `kind_of?` and `be_an_instance_of` checks for `instance_of?`. So be_an will also be true for every instance of any class that inherits from AR::Base::Session. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a

Comment: You could also use the #inspect method to compare the contents of the two objects. `assigns(:session).inspect.should == ActiveRecord::Base::Session.new.inspect`.