# Ruby's 'is_a?' is returning false for built-in types, what's happening?

Tags: ruby, arrays, oop, types, duck-typing

I've only been learning the deep parts of Ruby for a few months so apologies if this is a bit of a dumb question. I'm attempting to recursively iterate through an Array that *may* contain nested Arrays and as such I need to check the type of the current element. I have the following code as a small test:

```
arr = [ 1..2, [3..4, [5..6]], [7..8, [9..10]] ]

arr.each do |node|
  p node.class
  p node.instance_of? Array
end
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
Range
false
Array
false
Array
false
```

I expected the last two to return True, given I have an Array containing a Range and two nested Arrays.

What's even weirder, is if I write the following:

```
node.class.name == "Array"
```

It returns True, as it should.

What's happening here?

**Ruby Version:** MRI 1.9.3-p194

**Note:** I eventually realised that this was occurring due to the way I namespace my code using modules to avoid code-collision, like so, but also verify object identity in a naughty way:

```
module MyProg
  class MyClass
    attr_reader :my_array

    def initialize(size)
      @my_array = Array.new(size)
    end
  end
end

MyProg::MyClass.new
```

Doing this isolates your code but has the downfall of causing **all** class lookups to be resolved starting from under your namespace. This means that in the above example, `my_array.class` would actually resolve to *`MyProg::Array`* instead of the global Array class.

If you namespace like this and you still want to use this method, you can remedy it by using the double-colon global identifier before the class to force Ruby to begin lookup from the global namespace:

```
arr.is_a? ::Array
arr.is_a? ::String
```

Given Ruby's Duck Typing abilities however (and for better code maintenance later on), you should really be testing the *behaviour* of the object as-per Peter's suggestion below. As such I'm marking his answer as correct for some excellent help given to a learner!

Comment: Same Ruby version returns `true` for me for the last two cases.

Comment: I cannot replicate your results. Using MRI 1.9.3-p194 on Ubuntu, `instance_of?` returns True.

Comment: I couldn't determine exactly what was causing this. After rewriting the function within the unit test, it returned the right results. My theory is that somehow, MiniTest is altering the method in some way. I've resorted to checking behaviour as-per @Peter's suggestion which passes the test and gives the correct result so I'll update my question.

Comment: I get `true`s on MRI 1.9.3p125, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote another answer, but one major question is - why are you doing this? Why not, instead, just call `flatten` on the array so you just get the entries? Or, check for the *behavior* of the objects instead. You might need to give more detail about what you require.

Comment: I need to retain the structure of the Array as I'm converting it to a DAG from an S-expression (which is just a multi-dimensional array). If I use `flatten` I'll lose the structure and won't be able to determine if an Array is a child of another. Interestingly, I tried your solution of checking `__id__` and the object id was the same for both nodes. I'm guessing because they were nested within the parent Array (which has the same id)?

Comment: The __id__ depends on the instance of the `Array` class that is available when the objects are created. Still doesn't make a lot of sense that `is_a?` isn't working properly. But I think you can hopefully provide a solution that only cares about the behavior of the objects.

Answer (score 3):

You really mean `is_a?`, which is a more general test to see if the `node` is of type `Array`, rather than a specific instance of the specific `Array` class that you mention. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a) for more details. But if you just use `is_a?` everything will make sense.

Comment: I should mention the same output occurs if I use `is_a?`. I use `instance_of?` as I'm not checking inheritance, I only want to test for a specific class - Array in this case.

Comment: I do not understand how you can get the output you report with `is_a?`. Are you running this in a single Ruby script with no other patches or modifications happening? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Running the code (both with `instance_of?` and `is_a?`) in IRB or MiniTest returns the wrong output. Running it as a standalone script returns the right output. I haven't made any modifications and I don't think MiniTest does?

Comment: The problem will be that the instance of `Array` will be different - if you compare `Array.__id__` and `[1,2].class.__id__` you will probably find them different. I'll submit an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got these results.

```
Range
false
Array
true
Array
true
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p125