# Get the model an Active Record object is in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm making an ActiveRecord query that joins the contents of each of my models into an array called `@contents`. But I need to display the content different for data that comes from a specific model.

So in my view I need to perform some sort of test on the elements of my array:

```
<% @contents.each do |c| %>
  <article>
    <% if [TEST FOR EVENT] %>
      EVENT HTML
    <% elsif [TEST FOR POST] %>
      POST HTML
    <% end %>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

How do I get the model that `c` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the trick:

```
c.kind_of?(Event) #=> true or false
```

## Going deeper: [Ruby: kind_of? vs. instance_of? vs. is_a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a)

My short version of the comparison:

```
3.class #=> Fixnum
3.is_a? Integer #=> true
3.kind_of? Integer #=> true
3.instance_of? Integer #=> false
# is_a? & kind_of? can 'detect' subclasses, when instance_of? does not
```

Comment: Will accept in 4 mins. Thanks for the reference to the differences between kind_of and is_a and instance_of.

Comment: There's also `case c when Event then ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is_a?` method.

`<% if c.is_a?(Event) %>` or `<% if c.is_a?(Post) %>`

Simply pass the class name.