# Rails Parent.find method returns object of type Child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, model, find

I'm seeing an interesting behavior and would like some insight.

I have two models: Person & User.  User inherits from Person.  There is no users db table, just people.

When I search for a user I've created using Person's find model, I'm expecting to see an object of type person returned.  But its type is user.

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
@person.class 
# outputs 'User'
```

Can someone please explain why it wouldn't return a person object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the desired behaviour. The `type` column of the found person row contains the value "User". Because of that the returned type is `User`, too.

Remember that `User` also is a `Person`, so you can treat any `User` instance like it was a `Person` instance.

Comment: I would add that it can be easily tested with the method `@person.kind_of?(Person)` (should return true) when `@person.instance_of?(User)` should return false : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a