# Get first object of specific class from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have an array of active record objects.

I need to grab the first existing object in that array with a class of `post`, move it to a brand new array so that it no longer exists in the initial one.

What's the most optimal way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_array = [old_array.delete(old_array.detect { |object| object.is_a? Post })]
```

Comment: Yes! This works! How could I modify this so that it could check for multiple classes? So add it if it's one of many.

Comment: @JacksonGariety You can use `[String, OtherClass].include? object.class`

Comment: @JacksonGariety: You could use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) if you wanted to stick to `is_a?`.

Comment: Any reason to use `.is_a?` over `.include?`?