# How do I search a YAML file?

Tags: ruby

I have a YAML file `books.yaml`:

```
 - !ruby.object:Book
  title: Ruby for Newbz
  author: LeeRoy Jenkins
  category: Educational
```

I already have a method that adds books to this file, but I need a method that can search the YAML file using a regular expression. If no book matches the title then it should raise an exception `NoBookfound`. If there are any matches, that list should be returned to the caller.

Here is my existing code:

```
require 'yaml'
require './book'
class Library
  attr_accessor :books

  def initialize file_name = false
    @books = file_name ? YAML::load(File.read(file_name)) : []

  end

  def add_book(book)
    @books.push(book) 

  end

  def search_library(file_name , book) 
    if
      YAML::load(File.read(file_name)).include?(book) == false
      raise 'No Book Found'
    end
  end

end
```

This is something I tried for the exception portion, but I feel like I'm way off. I'm really new to Ruby and this seems to be a pretty hard task. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to test the class from the loaded object:

```
book = YAML::load(File.read(file_name))
raise 'No Book Found' unless book.kind_of? Book
```

There are also some `kind_of?` alternatives, which you can read about the differences on this [nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3893278/413494)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, I guess that book param is a Regexp object. 
I think you should remove the file_name param from search method, since the file is already loaded on initialize method.

My implemetation would be:

```
def search_library term
  @books.find_all {|b| b.title =~ term}
end
```

Comment: Actually, `file_name` refers to the YAML file and there is a seperate Book class that just initializes the three descriptors `@title` `@author` and `@category`

Comment: Yes, I got it, but I think it is a little bit confusing if you load the file two times. No to mention that you will lose all objects from add_book method. If you want to keep the file_name, I think that would be better if you make this method static: def self.search_library(file_name, term) ...

Comment: I see what you're saying, my instructor pointed this out as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have "@books" in an enumerable you can use the [`select` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to find books whose title have the search term as a substring.

```ruby
def search_library(term)
  matches = @books.select { |x| x.title.index(term) }
  raise "No books have title like '#{term}'" if matches.empty?
  matches
end
```

Comment: this seems to work well, thank you and everyone who replied for your feedback!

Comment: @HubertWolski: feel free to upvote answers you thought were helpful and choose one as the "correct" (or best, or your favorite) answer.

Comment: can't until i have a better rep otherwise i would :)