# Rails Web Service with Grape, returning vague error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

I am trying to create an API web service in Rails using Grape. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/making-a-rails-api-with-grap/).

I managed to get everything up and running and expected it to work perfectly. When I try to test my API endpoint however, I'm presented with a vague error. I am not sure where to start, as I don't know how to interpret the error returned. Here it is:

```
compared with non class/module

def rescuable?(klass)
  options[:rescue_all] || (options[:rescue_handlers] || []).any? { |error, _handler| klass <= error } || (options[:base_only_rescue_handlers] || []).include?(klass)
end
```

Here are the 20 last entries in my trace:

```
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:50:in `<='
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:50:in `block in rescuable?'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:50:in `any?'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:50:in `rescuable?'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:30:in `rescue in call!'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:25:in `call!'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/builder.rb:153:in `call'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:202:in `call!'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:190:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/api.rb:114:in `call'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/api.rb:44:in `call!'
grape (0.13.0) lib/grape/api.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
```

Can anybody please help me understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `klass <= error`, `error` is not a class or module, so that comparison is failing.  Instead, you want to check if `error.kind_of? klass` (or perhaps `error.instance_of? klass` if you want to ensure that `error` is an instance of that exact class.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3893305/1106267 for more on that distinction.

EDIT:

If you followed the linked tutorial verbatim, it's possible you're using deprecated methods in grape.  According to [the upgrade docs](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/483ec76810203c0bc18ef043a00824eb2f7869e7/UPGRADING.md), `error_response` (used in the tutorial to generate a custom response for `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` errors) should be replaced with `error!` if you're using grape >= 0.12.

Comment: Thanks @Charles. Could this be an issue with Grape, seeing as that snippet is part of the Grape gem. It's not something I added?

Comment: this helped a lot. After fixing this, I just needed to change my Model references from 'Graduate.all' to '::Graduate.all' and now everything works perfectly.