# Get model type from each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I'm combining two models in my controller, and trying to print them in a similar fashion, but I'd like to do an `if` statement in an `each` loop to distinguish one model from the other. My models are comments and likes.

In the controller:

```
@items = (@user.likes + @user.comments).sort{|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```

In my view:

```
<%= @items.each do |item| %>
  <% item.name %>
<% end %>
```

I need an `if` statement to say `IF comment` or `IF like` in the `each` loop. I've been drawing a blank on the situation.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have model `Like` and `Comment`

```
<%= @items.each do |item| %>
  <% if item.instance_of?(Like) %>
    Something for likes
  <% elsif item.instance_of?(Comment) %>
    Something for comments
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `item.class.name` as Nithin mentioned, and it'll work fine. However, the more idiomatic way is to use `instance_of?`. So it'd look like this:

```
if item.instance_of?(Post)
  # do something
elsif item.instance_of?(User)
  # do something else
end
```

Note you're not passing in 'Post' or 'User' as strings - you're passing in the Ruby class constants themselves.

On this topic, it's also worth knowing about Ruby's `is_a?` and `kind_of?` methods which work similar to `instance_of?` but return true if the instance you're testing is an instance of a subclass of the parameter you pass in (more info at [Ruby: kind_of? vs. instance_of? vs. is_a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a)).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to check for the class of the Item of interest.

Basically, each object belongs to a class, and the class name of a `comment` will be a `Comment` while that of a `like` will be a `Like`.

So, in the loop, check for the class name as:

```
<%= @items.each do |item| %>
  <% if item.class == Comment %>
    ...comments here
  <% elsif item.class == Like %>
    ...likes here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```