# How to understand Ruby interpreter/compiler technique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I want to know how ruby interpreter works.Well let's look at the bellow 
In irb console if write

```
Class.is_a? Class #=> returns -> true
```

I would like to know how this is returning true.
What is happening underneath.

```
class A
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end
A.is_a? A # returns false
```

Why it's returning false here? 
Can someone explain how this is being done underneath.I am not asking for `Ruby` obeject class hierarchy but look `Class.is_a? Class` is `true` then `A.is_a? A` should be true because A is a `Class`.But `A.is_a? A` is false why?
Another example

```
Module.is_a? Class # returns true
Class.is_a? Module # returns true
```

I mean how?
Because `Module` can't be instantiated where `Class` can be and there are other differences as well between `Mudule` and `Class`.
Then how come those expression returning `true`
that means there are some logic behind this.
Can someone explain that logic or the magic happening here.
I am really interested to know this.
Please help me understand `Ruby` interpreter technique
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Class.class #=> Class`. All classes are instances of `Class`. Since `Class` is a class, it is itself an instance of `Class`:). Confused? You should be! & btw this seems like a dup but I can't find a link atm.

Comment: Seriously confused.Because `Module.ancestors` => `[Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` and `Class.ancestors` => `[Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`.So Module is a ancestors of `Class`.But how they are tied togather.This is not the reason they have common ancestors.But there are other reasons here.BTW I have searched for same type of question but didn't get any.

Comment: `Module.is_a? Class #=> true` this makes sense because Module is a class; `Class.is_a? Module #=> true` since `Module` is a superclass of `Class` i.e. `Class` is an instance of `Class` which means it's a specialised `Module` so to speak. Anyway the link for which this question is a dupe covers everything. Best of luck down the rabbit hole. I admire you for seeking out how this all works... it's pretty fascinating.

Comment: I went through that url but that does satisfy me.So here is the biggest confusion 
`class A
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

class B < A
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end


class C < A
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end
`
According to your @sagarpandya82 comment `B.is_a? C` should return `true` as they are inheriting from class `A` but it is returning `false`.Do you know why?So I think this question is really not like that you said.Please remove the duplicate mark.

Comment: @monsur that comment is very unclear. First due to inheritance neither `B` nor `C` would require you to redefine `hello` in an identical fashion. Second `B` and `C` are not an `A`. `A`, `B`, and `C` are classes meaning `is_a?(Class) #=> true` because they are instances of the class Class. but `B.new` and `C.new` are `A`'s because the are instances of their class which is a subclass of `A`. That being said `A`,`B` and `C` are all `Module`s as well by the virtue explained above but their instances are not meaning `B.new.is_a?(Module) #=> false`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 here the `hello` method is not the fact.`A.class` => `Class` and `B.class` => 'Class' then why not `A.is_a? B` as both A and B are the instance of `Class`

Comment: @monsur one of the easiest ways to understand this is that `is_a?` concerns itself with `class`, inheritance and inclusions (which create a sudo anonymous superclass). e.g. `A.class #=> Class` thus `A` is a `Class`. `B.new.class #=> B` and since B inherits from `A` an instance of `B` is an `A`. further more `module R;end; class D; include R; end` now  D is not an `R` because `D` is a `Class` as previously established but `D.new` is a `R` because `R` has been injected into the inheritance chain for instances of `D` e.g. `D.ancestors #=> [D,R(Module),Object,Kernel(Module),BasicObject]`

Comment: It's pretty difficult to offer detailed explanations in comments, so I will cease to do so now. I can however offer you two more links: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34498578/5101493) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7675774/5101493) which both provide excellent answers and discussion in keeping with how the core classes are structured. Take your time to understand this, they are tricky.

Comment: @mosur to answer your last comment why is a Flower not a Tree they are both Plants? Why is a Monkey not a Fish they are both Animals? But a Tulip (an instance of a Flower) is a Flower and a Plant and a Blowfish (an instance of a Fish) is a Fish and an Animal.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes exactly.A monkey is not a fish even though they are animals then how come a `Module` is a `Class` what's happening here then.Certainly there is some logic.

Comment: @monsur: "a `Module` is a `Class`" – No, it's not. `Module` is a `Class`, **a** `Module` is a `Module`.

Comment: @monsur as @JörgWMittag pointed out **a** `Module` is not a `Class` the `Class` `Module` is a `Class`. So let's try it out `module R;end` then `R.is_a?(Class) #=> false`

Comment: Take a look at the book  Ruby Under a Microscope An Illustrated Guide to Ruby Internals By Pat Shaughnessy (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593275273.do). you can also read his blog http://patshaughnessy.net/