# Count class instances in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have rails app with models `Car` and `Wheel`.
And I have the method which returns an array of different objects. e.g.

```
array = [Car.new, Car.new, Wheel.new, Wheel.new, 'home', 'market', 'fun']
```

How to count `Car` instances and `Wheel` instances in an array?

I tried `array.include?(Car)` and `array.count(Car)` and they didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to fetch the instances of `Car`:

```
array.grep(Car).size
```

Comment: `Enumerable#grep` is definitely undervalued, love it!

Comment: I have to say that this is really a great way.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like below for counting Car instance:

```
array.count { |e| e.instance_of? Car}
```

or instead of `instance_of?` you can use `kind_of?` if that sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

`kind_of?` and `is_a?` are synonymous. They are Ruby's equivalent to Java's `instanceof`.

`instance_of?` is different in that it only returns `true` if the object is an instance of that **exact** class, **not a subclass**

```
array.count { |e| e.instance_of? Car}
```

For more details: **[`kind_of?` vs `is_a?` vs `instance_of?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a)**