# How to check for an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really new to Ruby. I have the following scenario where - I need to check if a keyword is an array or not in ruby?

Something like this -

```
if(value == array) {
do something
}
else 
do something
```

How can I do so using the if condition in ruby?

Any teachings would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try `if value.class == Array...`.

Comment: Yoru question is very unclear. What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails? What doe you mean by "I need to check if a keyword is an array or not in ruby?" A keyword is a keyword, it can never be an array. The only keywords in your code snippet are `if`, `do`, and `else`, and obviously none of them are arrays – they are keywords.

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

You can get the class of an Object with `.class`, and you can get a boolean response by using `.class.is_a?(Class)`:

```rb
ary = []
ary.class => Array
hsh = {}
hsh.class => Hash
float = 10.456
float.class => Float

# and get boolean responses like this:
hsh.class.is_a?(Hash) => true
hsh.class.is_a?(Array) => false
```

So you can handle each `Class` independently. If there are lots of potential classes, use a `case` statement:

```rb
case value.class
when Array
  # do something to the array
when Hash
  # do something to the hash
when Float
  # do something to the float
when Integer
  # do something to the integer
...
end
```

### Old:

You can use `.include?()`

```rb
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
array.include?('c') => true
array.include?('d') => false
```

So for your example:

```rb
if array.include?(value)
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Here "value" maybe an array name or a float name. So I need to figure out if that is array/float using if loop. Here "value" is not the typical values we have in array.

Comment: Are you saying "value" could be a class? like Array, Float, Integer, String, etc.?

Comment: Yes, value may be the name of array or name of a float. Suppose if value is an array it may have value = {0.1,0.2,0.3} .If it is a float just simply value = 0.1 or so.

Comment: `case value.class` -- `case value` is enough

Comment: @mechnicov, OP is new to Ruby and I thought that abstraction might be more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if value.is_a?(Array)
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

OR

```
if value.kind_of?(Array)
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

`#kind_of?` and `#is_a?` have identical behavior.
[Ruby: kind_of? vs. instance_of? vs. is_a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893278/ruby-kind-of-vs-instance-of-vs-is-a)